# mail reading problem?

Tags: java, email

i have com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message object, in that content i have the following format code,

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or distribution lists:

anandnarekar@gmail.coxm
```

An error occurred while trying to deliver this message to the recipient's e-mail address. Microsoft Exchange will not try to redeliver this message for you. Please try resending this message, or provide the following diagnostic text to your system administrator.

```
Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: delivery

anandnarekar@gmail.coxm
#< #5.0.0 smtp; 554 5.4.4 [internal] Domain Lookup Failed> #SMTP#

Original message headers:

X-AuditID: ac1ec426-b7b3aae0000036b3-7c-4e3009fd2d34
Received: from SVHJ0032 ( [172.30.1.11])    by svhj0367.ideaconnect.com (Symantec
 Brightmail Gateway) with SMTP id BA.D0.14003.DF9003E4; Wed, 27 Jul 2011
 18:22:13 +0530 (IST)
Message-ID: <1502435725.1311770110726.JavaMail.wasadmin@SVHJ0032>
Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2011 18:05:10 +0530
From: <ebill.mh@idea.adityabirla.com>
To: <anandnarekar@gmail.coxm>
Subject: Your Idea Bill
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="----=_Part_67575_1171670486.1311770110725"
Thread-Topic: rsweb_7202772011060510
X-Brightmail-Tracker: AAAAAQAAAZE= </pre>
> Blockquote
```

how can I retrieve the value of Thread-Topic?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the text that gets returned to you and look for "Thread-Topic".
Once you find it, you can use the indexOf and substring functions to parse out your topic.
Sample code shown below:

```
E:\jdk1.6.0_23\bin>type Test.java
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Thread-Topic: rsweb_7202772011060510";
    if (str.indexOf("Thread-Topic") != -1) {
      String topic = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 2);
      System.out.println(topic);
    }
  }
}
E:\jdk1.6.0_23\bin>javac Test.java

E:\jdk1.6.0_23\bin>java Test
rsweb_7202772011060510
```